# How to implement a QuerySet filter on Cartesian product/List of lists?

Tags: django, list, filter, django-queryset

I want to implement queryset filtering in Django depending on values of nested list, e.g.

```py
titles = [ ['nike', '38', 'blue'], 
          ['nike', '38', 'grey'],
          ['adidas', '38', 'blue'], 
          ['adidas', '38', 'grey'],
          ['salmon', '38', 'blue'], 
          ['salmon', '38', 'grey'] ]
```

The queryset is:

```py
queryset = Product.objects.all()
```

What are your suggestion to do something like below dynamically:

```py
# | mark means OR
queryset.filter(attribute__title='nike').filter(attribute__title='38').filter(attribute__title='blue') |
queryset.filter(attribute__title='nike').filter(attribute__title='38').filter(attribute__title='grey') |
queryset.filter(attribute__title='adidas').filter(attribute__title='38').filter(attribute__title='blue') |
...
queryset.filter(attribute__title='salmon').filter(attribute__title='38').filter(attribute__title='grey')
```

**If you are interested in Database schema:**

[image: Database scheme]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can dynamically generate querysets for each sub-list by repeatedly calling the `filter` method for each attribute in the sub-list, and then use the OR operator to create a union of all querysets:

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import or_

queries = []
for attributes in titles:
    query = queryset
    for attribute in attributes:
        query = query.filter(attribute__title=attribute)
    queries.append(query)
query = reduce(or_, queries)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear how your ORM models look like from the database schema you posted, but to give you an idea, this is how you implement dynamic filters using [`Q`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) objects:

```
from django.db.models import Q

titles = [['nike', '38', 'blue'],
          ['nike', '38', 'grey'],
          ['adidas', '38', 'blue'],
          ['adidas', '38', 'grey'],
          ['salmon', '38', 'blue'],
          ['salmon', '38', 'grey']]

colums = ['brand', 'size', 'color']

query = Q()
for title in titles:
    subquery = Q()
    for column_name, value in zip(colums, title):
        subquery &= Q(**{column_name: value})
    query |= subquery

queryset = Product.objects.filter(Q)
```

To clarify, the value of the `query` object will be similar to the following in the end:

```
(OR: 
    (AND: ('brand', 'nike'), ('size', '38'), ('color', 'blue')), 
    (AND: ('brand', 'nike'), ('size', '38'), ('color', 'grey')), 
    (AND: ('brand', 'adidas'), ('size', '38'), ('color', 'blue')),
    ...
)
```

You can adjust the values in the `columns` list to fit into your schema.

Comment: You can't use the `&` operator on the same m2m field with different values because Django will then apply those conditions to the same related objects, which will result in zero result. You simply have to call `filter` multiple times to make Django join the related table multiple times, like how the OP does it.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but unfortunately it didn't work, take a look on the accepted answer.